# MongoDb 4.0 use value of another field (trouble)

Tags: database, mongodb

By some reason mongoDB don't want to get value of field and instead of this I'm getting string with path to value, but not a value

this is my Query -

```
db.offices.update(
    {
        _id: ObjectId('____ID____')
    },
    {"$set": {
        'marketing': {
            "sale": {
                "regular": [
                    { "items": "$marketing_settings.recommended", "title": "$marketing_settings.tabtitle1"},
                    { "items": "$marketing_settings.alternative1", "title": "$marketing_settings.tabtitle2"},
                    { "items": "$marketing_settings.alternative2", "title": "$marketing_settings.tabtitle3"}
                ],
                "extra": {
                    "items": "$marketing_settings.extra_options",
                    "title": "Optional Extras"
                }
            },
            "lease": {
                "regular": [
                    { "items": "$marketing_lease_settings.recommended", "title": "$marketing_lease_settings.tabtitle1" },
                    { "items": "$marketing_lease_settings.alternative1", "title": "$marketing_lease_settings.tabtitle2" },
                    { "items": "$marketing_lease_settings.alternative2", "title": "$marketing_lease_settings.tabtitle3" },
                ],
                "extra": {
                    "items": "$marketing_lease_settings.extraOptions",
                    "title": "Optional Extras"
                }
            },
        }
    }}
)
```

but in result - I have

```
    "marketing": {
    "sale": {
        "regular": [{
            "items": "$marketing_settings.recommended",
title": "$marketing_settings.tabtitle1"
        }, 
.....
```

It works fine with mongo 4.4, but doesn't work witk 4.0.27

Comment: To update a field with another field value within a single update operation, you need to use the Updates with Aggregation Pipeline _feature_. But, this is available with MongoDB versions 4.2 and later only.

Comment: @prasad_ thank you! You was right. Updated version of mongo and all works for me!